# .env returns undefined for multiple files

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, npm, environment-variables

I  have two files using **.env** , both return `undefined` for variables, I have tried now to set a root .env for both front-end and backend, but still the .env variables are not loading.

in the front end any .env variables I try to test turn out undefined, I checked the code other people use and modified even further based on advice but its undefined...

[image]

in front end I have

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";
import StripeCheckout from "react-stripe-checkout";

require('dotenv').config();


toast.configure();

const PaymentButton = ({ name, price, description }) => {

  console.log(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
  console.log(process.env.TESTING)

 const handleToken =   async (token, addresses) => {
    const response = await axios.post(
      "http://localhost:3000/checkout",
      { token, product: { name, price, description } }
    );

   const { status } = response.data;

   console.log("Response:", response.data);

    if (status === "success") {
      toast("Success! Check email for details", { type: "success" });
    } else {
      toast("Something went wrong", { type: "error" });
    }
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="product">
        <h1>{name}</h1>
        <h3>Product price:  ${price}</h3>
      </div>
      <StripeCheckout
        stripeKey= {process.env.PRIVATE_KEY}
        token={handleToken}
        amount={price * 100}
        name={name}
        // billingAddress
        // shippingAddress
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

both return undefined

my .env file

```
PRIVATE_KEY = pk_test_FAKERUr

TESTING = Hello

TEST_KEY = sk_test_FAKEHIHI8pGQt
```

in backend

```
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.TEST_KEY);
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');


const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());



app.post('/checkout', async (req, res) => {

    }

    res.json({ error, status });
});
```

To see file structure

[image]

Comment: I've been update my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your .env it's looks like this:

```
PRIVATE_KEY = pk_teff23f23

TESTING = Hello

TEST_KEY = sk_test_f32f23f23f23  FAKE  Qt
```

> You only need to add `required('dotenv').config()` in your root app. `server.js` or `app.js`.

Now from your server, you can do it like this code below:

```
// your dotenv in the first line
require('dotenv').config();
const cors = require('cors');
const express = require('express');
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.TEST_KEY);
const uuid = require('uuid/v4');


// console.log environment variable
console.log(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY);
```

> Make sure your `require('dotenv').config();` in the first line and **make sure your `.env` file in the same root with your backend.**

**The only one reason why your backend can't get your `.env`** it's because your `.env` file is outside your backend. **Now**, move your `.env` file into your backend folder.

I hope it can help you.

Comment: I tried all the advice, but still its returning undefined, always I have problem with .env files...

Comment: Have you `require` your `.env` in the first line of your server and make sure your `.env` file in the same root with your backend.

Comment: so I need 2 .env files, one for frontend folder and one for backend folder?

Comment: I tried it but still issues, maybe .env is just bugging for me?

Comment: I think, if you already add `.env` in your backend folder and put your `require('dotenv').config();` in the first line of your `server.js`, than make sure to console.log it first. `console.log it first in below your require .env

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206828/discussion-between-titus-sutio-fanpula-and-jcx3x).